# How does this variable is not defined?

Tags: unit-testing, zend-framework, phpunit

I want to know how to test the models in zend framework, but it give me a error when I run the test, the code is the following:

this is the model I want to test:

```
<?php



class Application_Model_User extends Custom_Model_Base {
    protected $_table = 'user';
    protected $_primary = array('id');
    protected $_primary_ai = 'id';
    protected $_data = array();
    protected $_data_changed = array();
    protected $_readonly = array('id');
    static
    protected $_columns = array(
        'id',
        'login',
        'password_hash',
        'name',
        'surname',
        'gender',
        'street',
        'postal_code',
        'city',
        'mobile',
        'homephone',
        'email',
        'is_active');

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    static function create(array $data) {
        return parent::_create(
                $_table,
                get_class(),
                $data,
                self::$_columns,
                true
        );
    }

    static function load($id) {
        return self::_selectAndBind(
                get_class(),
                        self::getDefaultAdapter()
                        ->select()
                        ->from($_table)
                        ->where('id = ?', array($id)),
                true);
    }

    static function find($name, $order=null, $limit=null, $offset=null) {
        return self::_selectAndBind(
                get_class(),
                        self::getDefaultAdapter()
                        ->select()
                        ->from($_table)
                        ->where('name = ?', array($name))
                        ->order($order)
                        ->limit($limit, $offset)
        );
    }

}
```

it extends a base class, which is :

```
<?

abstract class Custom_Model_Base
{
    /** @var Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract */
    static protected $_db_default = null;

    /** @var Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract */
    protected $_db = null;
    protected $_table = '';
    protected $_primary = array();
    /** $var string indicates which column from pk using auto increment function, set to null if none column is using auto incrementation */
    protected $_primary_ai = null;
    protected $_data = array();
    protected $_data_changed = array();
    protected $_readonly = array();


    /**
     * @param Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract $adapter overrides global (static) adapter used for all models
     */
    protected function  __construct($adapter=null) {
        if ($adapter !== null) {
            if ($adapter instanceof Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract)
            {
                $this->_db = $adapter;
                return;
            }
            $this->_db = &self::$_db_default;
        }

    }

    /**
     * @param $default_adapter allows to set default adapter for whole model layer based on that class
     */
    static public function init($default_adapter = null)
    {
        if (self::$_db_default === null)
        {
            if (!is_null($default_adapter))
            {
                if (!$default_adapter instanceof Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract)
                {
                    throw new Exception('Provided adapter does not extend Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract');
                }
                self::$_db_default = $default_adapter;
            }
            else if (Zend_Registry::isRegistered('db'))
            {
                self::$_db_default = Zend_Registry::get('db');
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception('No default adapter provided for the model layer');
            }

        }
    }

    /**
     * @return Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract default database adapter
     */
    static public function getDefaultAdapter()
    {
        return self::$_db_default;
    }

    /**
     * Saves changed columns from the model object
     * @return bool success - true / failure - false
     */
    public function save()
    {
        $to_update = array();
        foreach(array_keys($this->_data_changed) as $col)
        {
            $to_update[$col] = $this->_data[$col];
        }

        if (count($to_update))
        {
            // create where clause
            $where = array();
            foreach($this->_primary as $pk)
            {
                $where = array($pk.' = ?' => $this->_data[$pk]);
            }

            return ($this->_db->update($this->_table, $to_update, $where) != 0);
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }


    public function  __set($n, $v)
    {
        if (!isset($this->_data[$n]))
        {
            throw new Exception('Column \''.$n.'\' doesn\'t exists');
        }
        else if (in_array($n, $this->_readonly))
        {
            throw new Exception('Column \''.$n.'\' is set as read-only');
        }

        if ($this->_data[$n] != $v)
        {
            $this->_data_changed[$n] = 1;
            $this->_data[$n] = $v;
        }
    }

    public function  __get($v)
    {
        if (!isset($this->_data[$n]))
        {
            throw new Exception('Column \''.$n.'\' doesn\'t exists');
        }
        return $this->_data[$n];
    }


}
```

my test code is :

```
<?php

require_once(APPLICATION_PATH.'/models/CustomModelBase.php');

class Model_User2Test 
    extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    protected $_model;

    public function setUp() {

        parent::setUp();

        $this->_model = new Application_Model_User2();

        //$foo = $this->getMock();
    }

    public function testCanDoTest() {
        $this->assertInstanceOf('Application_Model_User2', $this->_model);
        //$this->assertType('Application_Model_User2',new Application_Model_User2());
    }

    public function testCanFind() {
        $this->assertTrue(true);
        $this->_model->init();
        $this->assertNotNull($this->_model->find('admin'));
    }   
}
```

when I run the test,it give me error:

```
1) Model_User2Test::testCanFind
Undefined variable: _table
application\models\User2.php:57
tests\application\models\User2Test.php:27
```

why the _table is not defined? actually it is defined when I create the object? how could I fix it?

Comment: In some cases, I see you using `Application_Model_User2` instead of 1`Application_Model_User`. I assume this is just a typo?

Comment: @david, yes, david, it is a typo

Answer (score 2):

You declare `_$table` as protected:

```
protected $_table = 'user';
```

So you can't access it as you are doing through an instantion of the class. Only a class that inherits can do that. You need to declare it public, or use a getter/setter style access.

Edit:

```
static function load($id) {
    return self::_selectAndBind(
            get_class(),
                    self::getDefaultAdapter()
                    ->select()
                    // $this->_table not $table
                    ->from($_table)
                    ->where('id = ?', array($id)),
            true);
}
```

In your class, you're using $_table and not $this->_table. This is the same in another location. Check over to make sure you're properly accessing class variables.

Comment: changed the protected $_table as public $_table, but it is still the same error

Comment: Updated with more info. when accessing class variables you need to use `$this->variable`.

Comment: I changed the protected $_table as public in both Application_Model_User and Custom_Model_Base class, but it gives the same error

Comment: I changed it, but it gives me "PHP Fatal error:  Using $this when not in object context", can not use $this in a object ?

Comment: Since you need `$_table` in a static method, move it to a class constant using `const TABLE = 'user';` at the top and `self::TABLE` in the static methods.

Answer (score 1):

In your static method `Application_Model_User::find()`, you have this line in your query:

`->from($_table)`

But in this context, `$_table` is a local variable that never gets set. Sounds like you want to access `$this->_table` instead.

[ As a side note: since you have defined `find()` as a static method, you can run into issues when trying to reference `$this` during a static call. Of course, in your test, you do seem to call the `find()` on an *instance*, so you should be fine in this respect. Do you really need `find()` to be a static method?]

Comment: I just test the code written by others, so I can not change the access specifier of find(), in the base class, it provides the __set and __get method, so how can I fix the problem without change the access specifier? I do not know what to do

Comment: Then it looks like a failing test. Exactly what unit-tests are for. ;-)

Comment: but the application runs without problem

Comment: I cannot see how this model code actually works, referencing the _unset_ local variable `$_table`. Maybe the app in production mode is suppressing/catching errors and the `_selectAndBind()` method is doing some kind of magic to handle the missing table name?

Comment: I also confused about it, the constructor is protected, I do not even know how to create a object of it, it is really stupid code